# How to Install Plone on OS X

Tags: macos, installation, plone

Can someone walk me through a step-by-step process for installing Plone to OS X? I don't know the processes and differences in a unified installer or binary installer so I'd like to have someone walk me through the process of having it fully installed. Thanks!

Comment: This is likely off-topic for StackOverflow. Did you run into any specific, programming-related issues when following this - http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html#osx ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://docs.plone.org/quickstart/

Of the two, the binary installer is best for someone who just wants to try out Plone.

The unified installer is also good for trying Plone but is better suited to those who are comfortable with command lines (though it now has a nice text-based UI to guide you with the install). The unified installer is also a good way to set up Plone for development and for production (for relatively simple configurations).

There is now an even better way to evaluate Plone, using the Vagrant/VirtualBox development/evaluation install kit.